# any way to get business data using URL of yelp?

Tags: api, url, yelp

I am new to using `API of YELP` to get `business data`.

I have a only business URL like `"http://www.yelp.com/biz/1886-cafe-and-bakery-austin"` OR `"1886-cafe-and-bakery-austin"`.

Any way to get business perticular that url data using any API in YELP?

Please suggest me if any one have..

**NOTE: I solve issue: please refer below comment answer... thanks**

Comment: you can write a scrapper

Comment: can you suggest me any one?

Comment: i don't know if there is out of the box scrappers for yelp. I have seen a windows app which you can configure the scrapping. You can write your self with any language that provides a DOM manipulation functions and Network access.

Answer (score 3):

I solved issue to get venue business data using yelp API:

**API: http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/1886-cafe-and-bakery-austin**

Above api i got data.

Thanks